# Create a string with concatenation

Tags: java

I've the below string to be created.

```
The <a target="" href="http://google.com/search=xyz">xyz</a><a target="" href="http://google.com/search=xyz"><img src="http://google.com/small.gif" alt="" title="smallimage" border="0"></a> has all the search info.
```

I'm trying to do it as below.

```
String X = "The <a target="" href="http://google.com/search=xyz">xyz</a><a target="" href="http://google.com/search=xyz"><img src="http://google.com/small.gif" alt="" title="smallimage" border="0"></a> has all the search info."
```

But it is throwing me syntax error.

Here I've created another String named searchTerm as below.

```
String searchTerm = "Hello";
```

and i'm trying to create the final string by concatenation like below.

```
String X = "The <a target="" href="http://google.com/search="+searchTerm+"">xyz</a><a target="" href="http://google.com/search="+searchTerm+""><img src="http://google.com/small.gif" alt="" title="smallimage" border="0"></a> has all the search info."
```

and even this is not working.

please let me know how can i fix this.

Here i'm even confused about `< and >` tags, not only about the quotes

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to read from some html or using it for some other purpose

Comment: Using `String.format()` is much better and readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the quotes that you want to appear in the String.

```
String x = "<a target=\"...\" href=\"...\">...</a>";
```

Comment: And how about the `<` and '>'

Comment: those characters should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I wrote...

```
String s = "The <a target=\"\" href=\"http://google.com/search=xyz\">xyz</a><a target=\"\" href=\"http://google.com/search=xyz\"><img src=\"http://google.com/small.gif\" alt=\"\" title=\"smallimage\" border=\"0\"></a> has all the search info.";
System.out.println(s);
```

and here's the output I get....

```
The <a target="" href="http://google.com/search=xyz">xyz</a><a target="" href="http://google.com/search=xyz"><img src="http://google.com/small.gif" alt="" title="smallimage" border="0"></a> has all the search info.
```

Does this answer your question?